# Accessing a VM on DigitalOcean withpassword bypassing SSH verification

Tags: ssh, sftp

I have an ubuntu server on DigitalOcean, that uses SSH to connect.

I created a user with a specific home directory, to share with a third party so that they can connect via SFTP and send us files.

The user has a password, and I want the third party to access my VM without needing an SSH private key.

This is what I did so far:

```
adduser --home /somedir/another usernameX
```

I gave it a password, and it's done, now when I try to connect to the server, using this username and password, I get the following error:

```
$ ssh usernameX@x.x.x.x
usernameX@x.x.x.x: Permission denied (publickey).
```

What to do? And feel free to suggest a different way of doing this, I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: check /etc/sshd.config whether password authentication is turned off. I'd caution that using password authentication for a DigitalOcean machine is a dangerous game. There's literally hundreds of attempts each hour of crawlers trying to access your VM with random user names and passwords.

Comment: also check the sshd logs to see whether access fails for some other reason.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Is `/etc/sshd.config` specific to DigitalOcean or what? Usually it's `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. I have no experience with "Ubuntu server on DigitalOcean" whatsoever, but *maybe* you made an honest mistake and misled the OP inadvertently. Please review.

Comment: I made an honest mistake!